# Prevent direct call to my spring boot rest API

Tags: spring-boot, security

I have several REST services (on spring boot) used by a javascript file (website) and these services can be called directly by anyone (and you can see the API url/parameters with the developper console on any browser).
So I would like to prevent the direct calls to the API, exept of course from the front side of my app.

I saw that I can use an API key with spring security but is it reliable? Since I think you can see the key if you intercept the message with developper console.

Comment: Don't you have any authorization or security mechanism? Is there no login?

Comment: No there is no login, so no security or authorization are granted

Comment: The only way is to add kind of authentication if you want to avoid it. As you said the API key would help because it's easy to capture.

Comment: You can't, your browser just executes those requests directly as well, so you can't reliably differentiate between someone executing those calls directly, or your browser (since the web is stateless). Anyhow, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you clarify why you want to prevent direct calls?

Comment: Because I have POST services that add/modify data in the database. I don't have any DELETE services but I think it's still worrying to be exposed like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do are the following :

- Disable CORS in your springboot application by setting the following globally or per endpoint as you wish.

To set the CORS per endpoint :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Test testing(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="Test") String name) {
    System.out.println("in test");
    return new Testing(10, String.format(template, name));
}
```

- You can use spring security to preauthorize your controller endpoints to make sure that only the authorized has access to the controller.

Like for example :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/v2/"})
public class ExampleTestController {
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String test() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Using spring security is safe, as the user is always validated before access is granted . Even while using Oath2 the key generated is after validating the user login and the key can be used to validate every request to the controller by passing it in the header or using it in the rest template.

- Another way of isolating your rest endpoints is by using the load balancer (or ngnix or anything) to block requests to these endpoints from outside your domain.

Comment: I have a CORS control because it's seem like it's mandatory for the front to be able to call the API. So I've added the domain name of the website to the CORS configuration but I can still call the API directly. And it seems like my CORS works because when I deploy the site on localhost:3000 for example, I'll have a CORS error unless I add localhost:3000 on my CORS filter.

Comment: He has no Spring Security in place!

Comment: @Raikyn Oh, that's not safe at all then ! if you don't have a security system in place, please do that first. Spring security is easy enough to adopt and there are plenty guides.

Comment: Ok I'll add that! So if I use spring security for Cors control, that will prevent direct call to my API? The only allowed calls will be from the domain I'll put in the CORS configuration?

Comment: Yes, you can configure everything in spring.Please do read the documentation.you can change the localhost to the domain of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the all headers via HttpServlet request
2. For postman, checkout for postman-token header key

   String.valueOf(allHeadersValues).contains("postman") would work but will impact your system's performance negatively
3. For others, test for the DNT header key